# how to deploy functions without parsing errors

Tags: javascript, api, express, stripe-payments

**This code is showing me a parse error and I am unable to deploy my functions**

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const stripe = require("stripe")(
  "sk_test_51LBEnTSHwAWSpySp3vUeTA3xoJfuVPSOQt3i6njS9P8NJcxGD33g0h2dLJg62FItggGrjDkXRanyfaiknMEuidzu00Gfnw1SOi"
);

const app = express();

app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (request, response) => response.status(200).send("hello world"));

app.post("/payments/create", async (request, response) => {
  const total = request.query.total;
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount: total, 
    currency: "inr",
  });

  response.status(201).send({
    clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
  });
});
exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Here is the error I got when I tried deploying functions:

[image: Here is the error I got when I tried deploying functions]

Answer (score 0):

This is a lint error during deployment. You should check your lint configuration, and line 20 in index.js as the error message suggests.